# How do I completely rid my Rails 4.2 application of teamcity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I usually use Vim for Rails development and I decided to try out RubyMine to see what it was like.  It wasn't half bad, but I decided it was too much bloat.

Now however when I run `rake test` it is running tests "through" team city (I don't fully understand what it is doing).  At no point do I recall installing teamcity.  How can I completely get rid of it?  Before my tests were running cleanly with guard and minitest/pride.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try to understand what's happening but this worked for me:

```
cd /your/project/root
```

`rm -rf .bundle vendor && bundle`

My **~/.bundle/config:**

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_JOBS: '2'
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to run `spring stop` when you switch from RubyMine back to the command line and vice versa:

```
cd ~/code/MyAwesomeProject/
spring stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as [Saqib Razaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930690/saqib-razaq) said, the issue is related to spring.
As for me, I found useful gem [guard-spring](https://github.com/mknapik/guard-spring)
so, you could try the following:

> Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'guard-spring'
```

> And then execute:

```
bundle
```

> Add rules to Guardfile:

`bundle exec guard init spring`

and that will do the trick