# Issue with running tests in Rails after using Ruby Mine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I usually use Vim for Rails development, but I briefly used Ruby Mine for a few days.

Now I'm back to using Vim and when I start up Guard or run `rake test` it appears my tests are now being run via teamcity, as opposed to my previews setup.  I'm getting a ton of errors as well.

Here is an example of the output from `rake test`:

```
##teamcity[enteredTheMatrix timestamp = '2014-12-29T11:01:59.027-0500']

##teamcity[testCount count = '0' timestamp = '2014-12-29T11:01:59.028-0500']

##teamcity[testFailed name = 'test_current_user' message = 'Minitest::UnexpectedError: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)|n    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>|'' details = 'test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>|'' error = 'true' timestamp = '2014-12-29T11:01:59.150-0500']
```

Can anyone guide me in how I can fix this?  I'm truly puzzled, as I don't see any changes to my  Rails configuration files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the hidden .idea directory in your project's root path. The project files will regenerate correctly the next time the project is opened.

Comment: And how would one fix this issue without getting rid of the RubyMine project files stored in `.idea`?

Comment: @Torbjoern The project files will regenerate correctly the next time the project is opened.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I deleted `.idea` and reloaded the project. The `.idea` folder is back and so is the deluge of teamcity output when I run `rails test`.

Answer (score 2):

**Run `spring stop` inside the project directory while the IDE is running.**

For me this removed all teamcity output and restored the normal output formatting of `rails test`.

Per answer in linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644701/739373

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i believe would be to use gem [**guard-spring**](https://github.com/mknapik/guard-spring)

[See my answer here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680803/how-do-i-completely-rid-my-rails-4-2-application-of-teamcity/31628589#31628589)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post links as answers. If the links go offline, your answer becomes useless. Instead, use the relevant info to build your answer and use the links as reference only. Thanks.